# Implementing descriptors with dynamic field using metaclasses

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass, descriptor

I have user-defined class which implements the descriptor protocol. The descriptor is assigned to an attribute of the client class. Currently the descriptor uses a generic variable name, i.e the class name of the descriptor and a key.

I want the attribute to be defined dynamically depending on the name which is on the client class. I understand I need to use metaclasses for that, so this is what I tried:

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
        __counter = 0

        def __init__(self, field=None):
                self.field = field or '{}_{}'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.__counter)

        def __get__(self, obj, owner):
                print 'getter'
                return getattr(obj, self.field)

        def __set__(self, obj, val):
                print 'setter'
                setattr(obj, self.field, val)


class MyMeta(type):
        def __new__(mcl, name, bases, nspc):
                for k,v in nspc.items():
                        if isinstance(v, MyDescriptor):
                                nspc[k] = MyDescriptor(field=k)

                return super(MyMeta, mcl).__new__(mcl, name, bases, nspc)


class User(object):

        __metaclass__ = MyMeta

        desc = MyDescriptor()

        def __init__(self, desc):
                self.desc = desc
```

Now this seems to work, if I check the dict attributes of my User class I see the field value of MyDescriptor object has the value 'desc':

```
>>> User.__dict__['desc'].__dict__
{'field': 'desc'}
```

But when I'm creating a new object of `User`, I end up with a recursive loop which prints 'setter' and ends up with exception.

```
>>> User('x')
setter
setter
setter
setter
setter
...
```

Why is that happens? Why there is a recursive call to the `__set__` method when I try to initalize an object?

How can I assign a dynamic value to the Descriptor object, depending on the attribute name in the client class? (in the example above I use desc, but let's say I have something else there like name, location, etc..)

Comment: If you set `field` equal to the descriptor's name, `setattr(obj, self.field, val)` calls the descriptor again. The field name must be different from the descriptor's name. Use `self.field = '_' + field` or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aran-Fey, this solved my problem :-) if you put this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Eh, I don't know. Looks like a simple oversight to me, and we probably have a dozen duplicates of this question anyway. I don't think I can justify posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question to mark this question as answered.

Thanks to **@Aran-Fey** comment, my problem was I used the same value field as the attribute so `setattr(obj, self.field, val)` was called recursively on the lookup for `self.field` value. Changing the `self.field` value to be `'_' + field` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On your problem of exceeding recursion depth, an another solution to fix that would be to directly manipulate object dictionary like `obj.__dict__[self.field] = val`. I like this approach better because it does not require you to have an `__init__` inside the descriptor class just to set a fake attribute name in order to fix that issue of recursion that occurs on using `getattr()` and `setattr()`

Now for the dynamic naming of attributes, this is how I solved this problem. I know its little different to your approach but it worked for me.

```
class MyMeta(type):

    def __new__(mcs, cls, bases, dct):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if if isinstance(v, Descriptor):
                dct[k].attr = k
        return super().__new__(mcs, cls, bases, dct)


class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return instance.__dict__[self.attr]

class Positive(Descriptor):

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value < 1:
            raise ValueError("{}.{} can't be negative".format(
                instance.__class__.__name__, self.attr))
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self.attr] = value


class Rectangle(metaclass=MyMeta):
    length = Positive()
    breadth = Positive()

    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}({!r}, {!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.length,
                                       self.breadth)


r1 = Rectangle(4, 20)
r2 = Rectangle(100, 200)
print(r1, r2)
r1.breadth = 30
r2.length = 150
print(r1, r2)
```

**Output**

```
Rectangle(4, 20) Rectangle(100, 200)
Rectangle(4, 30) Rectangle(150, 200)
```

The way it works is by intercepting the descriptor instances from the class dictionary in the meta class and then adding a new attribute in descriptor instance's dictionary and sets its value actually to the descriptor instance name.

So in above example the `MyMeta` will iterate through the class dictionary and the moment it finds an attribute which is an instance of class `Descriptor` which `length` and `breadth` are, it will add an attribute `attr=lenght` and `attr=breadth` for `length` and `breadth` descriptor instnaces respectively.

Note this does not require you have a `__init__` in the descriptor class. Plus you can see the metaclass isn't descriptor specific, you can use the same metaclass and it will work for any descriptor, the only thing you need to do is create a new descriptor class by just inherit from `Descriptor` class

Answer (score 0):

Hello Everyone Let me show you how to Write State of the art descriptors using Python Meta class, How to Perform  Validation on them. and How to define your Own Datatype with Metaclass

```
__Author__ = "Soumil Nitin SHah "
__Version__ = "0.0.1"
__Email__ = ['soushah@my.bridgeport.edu',"shahsoumil519@gmail.com"]
__Github__ = "https://github.com/soumilshah1995"

Credits = """  Special Thanks to David Beazley for his Tutorials """

from inspect import  Parameter, Signature
import datetime


class Descriptor(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):

        print(" __get__ ")
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
        # This will return Value

        # if instance is not None:
        #     return self
        # else:
        #     return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):

        print(" __set__ ")
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        print(" __delete__ ")
        del instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Object Descriptor : {}".format(self.name)


class Typed(Descriptor):
    ty = object

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.ty):
            raise TypeError('Expected %s' % self.ty)

        super().__set__(instance, value)


class PositiveInterger(Descriptor):

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError ("Value cannot be less than 0")


class Sized(Descriptor):

    def __init__(self, *args, maxlen, **kwargs):
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if len(value) > self.maxlen:
            raise ValueError('Too big')
        super().__set__(instance, value)


def make_signature(names):
    return Signature(
        Parameter(name, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
        for name in names)


class Integer(Typed):
    ty = int


class Float(Typed):
    ty = float


class String(Typed):
    ty = str


class StructMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, base, clsdict):

        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, clsname, base, clsdict)
        sig = make_signature(clsobj._fields)
        # print("Sig", sig)
        setattr(clsobj, '__signature__', sig)
        return clsobj


class Structure(metaclass=StructMeta):

    _fields = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # print("**kwargs", kwargs)
        # print("*Args", args)

        bound = self.__signature__.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        # print("bound", bound)

        for name, val in bound.arguments.items():
            # print(name, val)
            setattr(self, name, val)


class Stock(Structure):

    _fields = ['name', 'shares', 'price', "number", "fullname"]

    name = String('name')
    shares = Integer('shares')
    price = Float('price')
    number = PositiveInterger('number')
    fullname = Sized('fullname', maxlen=8)

    def methodA(self):
        print("Total Shares {}".format(self.shares))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Stock(name="Soumil", shares=12, price=12.2, number =2, fullname='aaaaaa')
    print("="*55)
    print(obj.methodA())
```